# Checkbox to change textdecoration input field

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checked, text-decorations

With javascript, i want my checkbox to change the text decoration of an input text field. 
So when it's checked, the text in the input text field turns bold.

Remember i'm learning so i'm not a pro as you guys ;)

I thought something like this;

```
var checkbox = create("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = "checkboxId" + counter;
    div.appendChild(checkbox);
    checkbox.onClick="boldChange(this)"

var input = create("input");
    input.type = "input";
    input.id = "inputId" + counter;
    div.appendChild(input);



function boldChange()
var boldgroup = document.getElementsByName(el.name);
for (var b=0; boldgroup[b]; ++b)
inputId.style.textDecoration = boldgroup[b].checked ? 'bold' : 'none';
}
```

How can i make this work?
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: `text-decoration: bold` is not valid CSS, IIRC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working JSFiddle example based on your code above: [Link to example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/DFZyU/)

Code snippet: (place below `</body>` so that all of DOM is loaded)

```
<script>
    var div = document.getElementById('div'),
    counter = 0;

    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = "checkboxId" + counter;
    div.appendChild(checkbox);
    checkbox.onclick = boldChange;
    counter++;

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.id = "inputId" + counter;
    div.appendChild(input);



    function boldChange() {
        input.style.fontWeight = (checkbox.checked)?'bold':'normal';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Opoe: You were definitely on the right track, just had to make a few tweaks to your code :)